# Does this matrix has a single LU decomposition?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, lu-decomposition

Let A be equal to this matrix:

[image]

Does this matrix has a single LU decomposition?

It is simple to find a decomposition without permutations. However how can I tell if there is more than one?

Basically, I am asking if 2 decompositions with the form A=LU exist for this matrix. Obviously you could find more decompositions but with the form PA=LU.

Comment: LU decomposition works for invertible matrices and your matrix ia not invertible.

Answer (score 0):

Because $A$ isn't invertible, there are many possibilities without permutations. Here are two:

$$\left(\begin{matrix}
    1 & 2 & 3 \\
    1 & 2 & 4 \\
    1 & 2 & 5
\end{matrix}\right) = \left(\begin{matrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 \\
    1 & 1 & 0 \\
    1 & 2 & 1
\end{matrix}\right)\cdot\left(\begin{matrix}
    1 & 2 & 3 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 \\
    0 & 0 & 0
\end{matrix}\right) = \left(\begin{matrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 \\
    1 & 1/2 & 0 \\
    1 & 1 & 0
\end{matrix}\right)\cdot\left(\begin{matrix}
    1 & 2 & 3 \\
    0 & 0 & 2 \\
    0 & 0 & 0
\end{matrix}\right)
$$